# ruby push method is alternating

Tags: ruby, push

```
cool_words = []

while true

    cool_words.push gets
    break if gets.chomp == ''

end

puts cool_words
```

It is only pushing the first entry then the third and then the fifth.  I think it is the way I have it breaking out of the loop because without the `break` method it doesn't happen.

I need it to `break` out of the loop when I hit enter on an empty line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: nobody asked, but if you decide to apply some functional programming  at some point of the learning process: `cool_words = $stdin.lines.take_while(&:present?)`. (granted, `present?` is in active_support and must be required (or implemented, one line), but you get the point ;-))

Comment: @tokland If you don't want ActiceSupport or a monkey-patch for something so simple, `take_while { |line| not line.chomp!.empty? }` is still easy enough to read.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, I know, but I was trying to sell FP with my best ads :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `gets` *twice* in the loop. The first time it is being pushed into the array. The second time it is comparing against an empty string for loop breaking. But each time it is asking for a new line.

You only want to call `gets` one time per loop. So you can save it in a variable, and then use that variable multiple times later in the code.

```
cool_words = []

while true
    line = gets
    cool_words.push line
    break if line.chomp == ''
end

puts cool_words
```

UPDATE: @MicahelKohl in the comments points out that you can accomplish the above task more elegantly like this:

```
cool_words = []

until (line = gets).to_s.chomp.empty?
    cool_words << line
end

puts cool_words
```

Comment: Why use `while true` (Ruby has a generic `loop do` for that btw) and `break` when you have a loop condition: `until (line = gets.chomp).empty? cool_words << line end`

Comment: @MichaelKohl, I updated my answer to include that more elegant construct.

Comment: You should probably check the case of #gets returning nil, although the OP does not ask for it. One way to do it (but not beautiful) is `until (line = gets).to_s.empty?`.

Comment: @eregon `gets` only returns `nil` on `Ctrl-D`, doesn't it? Good point though.

Comment: @MichaelKohl It does on Ctrl-D but also on any kind of EOF (so if you pipe some file to stdin it will fail if it does not have a blank line)

Comment: @eregon, good point. Added that to the answer. I also noticed that the original code stored the non-chomped version, so I moved the chomp outside of the assignment as well.